# Sed to loop through file and replace placeholder variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, debian

I was hoping to use bash to loop through a file and turn all placeholder varialbes into real variables:

- $PLACEHOLDER_USER -> $USER
- $PLACEHOLDER_STATE -> $STATE

It needs to work with any variable starting with placeholder and turn it into its real variable. This is the code I have so far:

```
$FILE="/mytest.conf"
sed -i "s/$var1/$var2/g" "$FILE"
```

However I'm not sure how I make it loop through the entire file, and I'm not sure how I can make it with any variable which starts with `$PLACEHOLDER_`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `mytest.conf` and its expected output.

Answer (score 3):

The default action of `sed` is to read and print every line of the input file.  You can modify this behavior in various ways by writing a `sed` script.  A typical script would be something like

```
sed -i "s/\\\$PLACEHOLDER_USER/$USER/g;s/\\\$PLACEHOLDER_STATE/$STATE/g" file
```

Pay attention to the quoting here; the double quotes allow the shell to replace `$USER` and `$STATE` with their values from the environment, while the backslashed dollar signs will not be substituted.  So the shell performs some substitutions, and by the time `sed` actually runs, the script has become

```
sed -i 's/\$PLACEHOLDER_USER/fred/g;s/\$PLACEHOLDER_STATE/Arkansas/g' file
```

(I supplied single quotes here to emphasize that no further substitution will take place.)

In the more general case, `sed` has no access to your environment variables, but you can write a shell script which generates a `sed` script from your variables.

```
env | sed 's%^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)%s/\\\$PLACEHOLDER_\1/\2/g%' | sed -f - file
```

This is somewhat tricky.  The output from the first `sed` script is another `sed` script which is read by another `sed` instance with `sed -f -`.  (This is not supported on all platforms, but should at least work on Linux.  If yours does not support this, you can work around it by writing the script to a temporary file, or using a command substitution.)

`env` lists your environment variables.  The first `sed` script will prefix each variable name with `\$PLACEHOLDER_` and generate a snippet of `sed` to replace any occurrence of that with its value from the environment.  (Caveat: If the value contains regex metacharacters, you will need a significantly more complex script.  If the values can contain slashes, you need to replace the slash delimiter with another delimiter; you can use any ASCII character you like.)

Comment: Thanks for this, it was exactly what I needed! If you want the output to go to a different file instead, you can omit the `-i` option, and add `> output.conf` to redirect sed's output to the file. It's also important to note that when doing this on Mac OS X, you need to use `-i ""` instead of just `-i` to edit in place because Mac OS X derives from BSD and uses the BSD flavor of sed.