# Copying files - Will it equate the variables on copy?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, debian

If I had the following setup on my files, just as an example:

**settings.sh**

```
MYUSER="tom"
```

**content.txt**

```
username="$MYUSER"
```

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./settings.sh

cp /home/content.txt /configuration.conf
```

Since deploy.sh knows the value of MYUSER, when it copies content.txt to configuration.conf, what will be the contents of the file?

1. Option 1: username="$MYUSER"
2. Option 2: username="tom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp /home/content.txt /configuration.conf
```

Will copy the source file to the destination file `"as is"` without expanding/resolving variables in the source. So it will be option 1: `username="$MYUSER"`

**UPDATE:**

Instead of copying using `cp` you can use `sed` which will replace and copy as this command:

```
sed "s#\$MYUSER#$MYUSER#g" /home/content.txt > /configuration.conf
```

Comment: I am trying to move a file from one place to another whilst also putting in the variables from file which initiated the copy into the new file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220612/sed-to-loop-through-file-and-replace-placeholder-variables

Comment: Oh ok that question. You didn't need to create a duplicate question. Could have just updated that one.

Comment: @Jimmy: See the **UPDATE** section now.

Comment: Thank you, but the trouble is that will only with the myuser variable, I was hoping this would work for any variable. For example "if you find a variable which starts with PLACEHOLDER_, remove it to create the original variable.

Comment: But are are all `PLACEHOLDER_` variable defined? What if there is an undefined one?